# Writing Yule-Walker Equations for AR(2) with Missing Term

Tags: time-series, estimation, autoregressive

I was wondering how you would find the Yule-Walker equations for an AR(2) (or, really, any AR(P)) stationary time-series model, where there is a "missing" term. For example:

$$ X_t - \phi\frac{1}{4}X_{t-2} = \epsilon_t $$

Where $\epsilon_t \sim WN(0,\sigma^2)$.The "missing" term is the $X_{t-1}$.

Writing the Yule-Walker, my attempt was:

\begin{align*}
   \gamma(0) - \theta\frac{1}{4}\gamma(2) &= \sigma^2 \\\\
   \gamma(1) - \theta\frac{1}{4}\gamma(1) &= 0 \\\\
   \gamma(2) - \theta\frac{1}{4}\gamma(0) &= 0
\end{align*}

But I was unsure if this was correct or not, since we don't end up with an n x n matrix (and our book does not provide an example of anything different - undergrad introduction to time-series).